# Multiple Query and Ref Firebase Database Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database looks like this:

[image: database]

From this query

```
String currentUserID = FirebaseAuth
                            .getInstace()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getUid();

DatabaseReference favorsRef = FirebaseDatabase
                                        .getInstance()
                                        .getReference()
                                        .child("favors");
Query myChatsQuery = favorsRef
                        .orderByChild("uid")
                        .equalTo(currentUserID);
```

I need to create other query to get just the tuples from myChatsQuery who has the child called "messages". If the tuple doesn't have the child "messages", I don't want to insert it in my new query.

So, How I can create a query from other query?

Help me please,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I get you correctly, you want to check which of those `uids` have the child called messages, and if they have you want to do something with it, right?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit exactly. First I check in favors those children who have the uid that I want (equals to currentUserID) because not all of them have the same uid. And then I need to check between all the children who have the uid=currentUserID which of those have a child called messages to do something with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `orderByChild()` does not work on multiple same fields at once, so you may have to do the job in two steps.

First you can run an `orderByChild()` query looking for the `currentUserId` and then add all those that match to an ArrayList and then run `orderByChild()` in those found `uids` for `messages`.

This looks something like this, in code:

```java
reference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(currentUserId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                              array.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                  )};
```

This code above adds `uids` matching `currentUserId` to the ArrayList `array`.

```java
databaseReference.child(array.get(0)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                           if(dataSnapshot.child("messages").exists())
                           // do your thing

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }

                    )};
```

You can also just use a for loop to go through all the values in the `array`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution won't work because you cannot use `.orderByChild("messages")`. messages is not a property so you can order according to it. Furthermore, there is no need to add two listeners in order to verify the `message` node for existens.

Comment: Actually I need to work with the list resulting, so how can I implement the first solution w ArrayList?

Comment: So you provided the same exact answer as mine, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, I think the answer almost matches yours, I am removing this code and giving another solution from the first approach. Apologies!

Comment: @esterrrsinH, glad to help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("favors").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(ds.child("messages").exists()) {
                //Do what you need to do
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see, you can solve this by querying the database only once.